# Wild Card colour change rule

Tags: uno

When using a Wild Card, can we say the same colour as the current colour in the game?

E.g. If the current colour was red and my brother played a Wild Card and said the colour will stay red so that he can discard his red card and win. Is it the correct way?

I felt that a change of colour should have happened?

Comment: Either a) your brother should have just played his red card, guaranteeing that he could play his wild card the next turn or b) he played a Wild Draw 4 in a two-player game, which meant he'd be next to play, but he violated the rule of not playing the Wild Draw 4 if you have a card of the current colour.

Answer (score 12):

According to the [official rules](https://service.mattel.com/instruction_sheets/42001pr.pdf) found via a google search 'uno rules' (emphasis mine):

> Wild Card - When you play this card, you may change the color being played to any color **(including the current color)**.

This means that when you play a Wild Card you can name the current color.

Comment: And you can only play ONE card each turn. I.e. you can't play a Wild Card and then another card in the same turn.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you don't have a turn after using a wild card.

Second, Your brother didn't violate any rules. If the going color is red and he used the wild card to keep the color to red only- there's no fault in that.